Intensity of light - questions about the particle standard definition and concerning the units
In the $5.111$ MIT class, lecture $3$, it is written on the last slide "intensity of light = photons per second". Intensity is previously defined in the lecture as the square of the amplitude of a wave of light.
Later, in an exercise (problem set of lecture $4$), intensity is defined in $J/s$.
My questions are:

Which of the correct unit is the standard one for intensity: photons$/s$ or $J/s$ ?
How any of these two match the $3^{rd}$ definition of the intensity - as the square of the amplitude of the wave - since the amplitude of a wave has no units ? How do the seconds get to appear ?


Both are wrong; intensity has to be energy per unit time per unit area. The link above has a very good answer.

I have read the link. What I still don't get, however, is why all the intensity definitions in the Wikipedia article linked have units, while an amplitude (squared or not squared) does not have units ?

@niobium Who said the amplitude has no units?

Only probability amplitude has no units
